# Why do Mono applications only start from their own directory?

Tags: linux, path, gnome-shell, mono

If I want to run the application `monodevelop`, I need to chdir to `/usr/lib/monodevelop/Bin` and then execute `./MonoDevelop.exe`. This is the same for all other Mono applications such as `banshee`, `tomboy`, etc.

If I attempt to run the Mono applications from another location by simply running `monodevelop`, or even from their own directory, I get *TypeInitializationExceptions* like this:

> behrooz@behrooz:/usr/lib/monodevelop/bin$ monodevelop
> FATAL ERROR [2012-05-04 11:24:39Z]: MonoDevelop failed to start. Some
> of the assemblies required to run MonoDevelop (for example gtk-sharp,
> gnome-sharp or gtkhtml-sharp) may not be properly installed in the
> GAC. System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by
> the type initializer for Gtk.Application --->
> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: glibsharp_g_thread_supported   at
> (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Thread:glibsharp_g_thread_supported
> ()   at GLib.Thread.get_Supported () [0x00000] in :0
> at Gtk.Application..cctor () [0x00000] in :0    ---
> End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
> MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions
> options) [0x0007e] in
> /home/behrooz/Desktop/Monodevelop/monodevelop-2.8.6.5/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:95
> at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0004f] in
> /home/behrooz/Desktop/Monodevelop/monodevelop-2.8.6.5/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:503

Why is that?

I have tried reinstalling all Mono, Wine, GTK, Glib, X, Gnome packages.

```
apt-get --purge --reinstall install $(dpkg --get-selections | grep mono | grep install | grep  -v deinstall | awk'{print $1}')
```

I also tried strace on "open" and got nothing by myself.

System Configuration:

- Debian 6.0-updates 64 bit
- Kernel 3.2.0-2, 3.2.0-1, 3.1 and 3 EDIT: not a kernel thing
- Gnome 3.4  EDIT:but a gnome thing
- Mono 2.10.5

  ```
  TLS:           __thread  
  SIGSEGV:       altstack  
  Notifications: epoll  
  Architecture:  amd64  
      Disabled:      none  
      Misc:          softdebug   
      LLVM:          supported, not enabled.  
      GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
  ```

update: with upgrading to the new MonoDevelop 3.0.2 and latest Mono, I can run MonoDevelop with command `monodevelop` in terminal, no chdir. but gnome-shell cannot run it.

Finally found it:
as root:

```
 cd /usr/local/
 find | grep mono|xargs rm -rf
 # Use with caution/some applications may get messed up (stellarium has MONOchrome images...)
```

Comment: Please tell me you don't really have to type "Monodevelop.exe".  At this point, it's pretty obvious that "file extensions" were a terrible mistake.  There's no reason to perpetuate them beyond Windows.

Comment: @BruceEdiger:Sorry, but this is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've built and installed `monodevelop` from source - did you do the same for the dependencies like `gtksharp`? Since `banshee` and `tomboy` are broken, it sounds like you have a dependency shared between the broken programs, and that's an obvious candidate. Do CLI mono apps work?

From the [MonoDevelop build documentation](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Building_MonoDevelop):

> We strongly recommend you install everything from packages if possible. If not you, you should use a Parallel Mono Environment. Do not install anything to /usr or /usr/local unless you completely understand the implications of doing do.

If the other mono applications will only run from the installed `monodevelop` tree, and reinstalling packages hasn't helped, you might have a mess of extra stuff floating around that the source install has added which is interfering with `mono` finding its libraries, possibly with hardcoded paths into the `monodevelop` install.

My Debian-fu is not strong, but there should be a way of identifying files in `/usr` that `dpkg` doesn't know about, that might be a place to start.

Comment: Wow, It's true, But how on earth could it have this effect after 6 month?

Comment: @Behrooz I'm guessing here, but if it loaded something into a shared location that mono uses, it could hang around until it's cleaned up manually. Something like the GAC or the pkg-config stuff it uses when building could affect other software, especially if that was also built from source.